# Getting 404 page not found error while using Artifactory as proxy for the GitHub repository where my Maven package is published

Tags: artifactory, github-packages, maven-package

I have published Maven package into GitHub and Im trying to use Artifactory as an proxy to fetch the Maven packages from GitHub repository. For this, I have created one remote repository in Artifactory and configured with GitHub repo URL, I have set Repository layout and remote layout mapping to 'maven-2-default'.. And for authentication, I have entered my GitHub username and PAT(with write permission to packages) in remote authentication section. After configuring all settings in Artifactory, I clicked on test icon to test the connection, then I see "Connection failed: Error 404: Not Found" error message.
I have verified that URL and PAT are valid but still getting 404 error

Looking for the help to fix this 404 error and make successful connection. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a lot of information missing here.
Which type of remote repository you are using? With which client you try to fetch the package?
What is the URL you are using on the remote repository on Artifactory?
What do you see in the artifactory-request.log and the artifactory-request-out.log?
I also suggest to use this REST API to debug this:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-TraceArtifactRetrieval

Comment: I have created maven remote repository in ArtifactoryOSS 6.17.4 and configured the URL as https://maven.pkg.github.com/<GitHub-Organization>/<GitHub-Repository>.

Comment: Logs showing in request log as below
|REQUEST|10.92.168.144|non_authenticated_user|GET|/ui/admin/repositories/remote/github-maven-remote|HTTP/1.1|401|0

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed by modifying URL in remote repository. Intially I have entered URL as https://maven.pkg.github.com//. Then I modified it to https://maven.pkg.github.com////maven-metadata.xml.
Its working now, thanks.